# How can I create an Excel table using NPOI XSSF

Tags: excel, f#, npoi, xssf

I have tried to create a table using NPOI 2.5.1 using the following code (trying to use examples from NPOI samples, and from the Apache POI code). It generates a file, but Excel finds a problem when opening it. Trying to recover removes the table part (There is us no table when the Excel file is opened).

Would you have any idea on how to modify the following code (in F#) ? (or a working sample of generating a spreadsheet with a table ?)

Thanks a lot

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.IO
open NPOI.SS.UserModel
open NPOI.SS.Util
open NPOI.XSSF.UserModel
open NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Spreadsheet


//write headers at the top of the sheet
let initSheet (sheet:ISheet) (headers:#seq<string>) = 
  //freeze below top row, on the left of first column
  sheet.CreateFreezePane(1, 1)
  let mutable col = 0
  let row = sheet.CreateRow(0)
  for header in headers do      
    row.CreateCell(col).SetCellValue(header)
    col <- col + 1

    
let autoSizeColumns (headers:#seq<string>) (sheet:ISheet) = 
  for col in 0 .. Seq.length headers - 1 do      
    sheet.AutoSizeColumn(col)


let generateWorkbook fileName headers = 
    let workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()

    let nHeaders = Seq.length headers

    let DAILY = "Daily"
    let END_OF_MONTH = "EOM"
    let YTD = "Ytd"
    let ALL_SHEET_NAMES = [DAILY; END_OF_MONTH; YTD] 


    let mutable col = 0
         
    //create sheets
    ALL_SHEET_NAMES
    |> List.map workbook.CreateSheet
    |> ignore
    
    //use the first one
    let sheet = workbook.GetSheet(DAILY)


    //====================================================
    // 
    // Here starts the "failed" attempt to create a table
    // 
    //====================================================

    //create table
    let s = sheet :?> XSSFSheet
    let table = s.CreateTable()
    let cttable = table.GetCTTable()
    cttable.id <- 1u

    //name
    table.Name <- "MyTableName"
    table.DisplayName <- "MyTableName"

    //show headers, not totals
    cttable.headerRowCount <- 1u
    cttable.totalsRowCount <- 0u

    //area
    let startRef = CellReference(0,0)
    let endRef = CellReference(70000, Seq.length headers - 1)
    let tableArea = AreaReference(startRef, endRef)
    let mutable areaRef = tableArea.FormatAsString()
    let rowCount = (tableArea.LastCell.Row - tableArea.FirstCell.Row) + 1
    let minimumRowCount = 1u + cttable.headerRowCount + cttable.totalsRowCount
    if uint32 rowCount < minimumRowCount then
      invalidArg "row count" <| "AreaReference needs at least " + string minimumRowCount + " rows, to cover at least one data row and all header rows and totals rows"
    
    //strip the sheet name
    if areaRef.IndexOf('!') <> -1 then
      areaRef <- areaRef.[areaRef.IndexOf('!')+1..]

    //update
    cttable.ref <- areaRef
    let autoFilter = new CT_AutoFilter()
    autoFilter.ref <- areaRef
    cttable.autoFilter <- autoFilter
    table.UpdateReferences()
            
    //number of columns
    if cttable.tableColumns = null then
      cttable.tableColumns <- new CT_TableColumns()
    if cttable.tableColumns.tableColumn = null then
      cttable.tableColumns.tableColumn <- new List<_>()
    let createColumn () =
      let mutable id = 0u
      for i in 0 .. cttable.tableColumns.tableColumn.Count - 1 do
        id <- max id cttable.tableColumns.tableColumn.[i].id
      id <- id + 1u
      let col = new CT_TableColumn()
      col.name <- "Col " + string id
      cttable.tableColumns.tableColumn.Add(col)
      cttable.tableColumns.count <- uint32 cttable.tableColumns.tableColumn.Count

    let columnsCount = cttable.tableColumns.count
    let newColumnsCount = tableArea.LastCell.Col - tableArea.FirstCell.Col + 1s
    if uint32 newColumnsCount > columnsCount then
      for i in columnsCount .. uint32 newColumnsCount - 1u do
        createColumn()      
    
    //write headers
    initSheet sheet headers

    //headers
    table.UpdateHeaders()

    //====================================================
    // 
    // Here ends the "failed" attempt to create a table
    // 
    //====================================================

    //table values (date in first column, values in following columns)
    let mutable x = 1.0
    for i in 1 .. 70000 do
      let row = sheet.CreateRow(i)
      for j in 0 .. 3 do
        let cell = row.CreateCell(j)
        if j = 0 then
          cell.SetCellValue(DateTime.Now)
        else
          cell.SetCellValue(x)
        x <- x + 1.0
        
    //auto-resize all columns on all sheets
    ALL_SHEET_NAMES
    |> List.map workbook.GetSheet
    |> List.iter (autoSizeColumns headers)

    let sw = File.Create(fileName)
    workbook.Write(sw)
    sw.Close()


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let headers = ["Date"; "A"; "B"; "C"]
    let fileName = @"C:\test.xlsx"
    generateWorkbook fileName headers
    0
```

Comment: Would it be helpful if the example uses EPPlus?

Answer (score 2):

Using EPPlus:

```
open System.IO
open OfficeOpenXml

let createTable filePath (sheetName : string) tableName data headers (startRow,startCol) =
    let fi = new FileInfo(filePath)
    using (new ExcelPackage(fi)) (fun p ->      
        let wb = p.Workbook
        let ws = 
            if wb.Worksheets |> Seq.map (fun s -> s.Name) |> Seq.contains sheetName then
                wb.Worksheets.[sheetName]       //if the sheet already exists, reference it
            else wb.Worksheets.Add(sheetName)   //otherwise, create it

        //helper function to write data based on the start row and column
        let writeData iR iC =
            data
            |> Seq.iteri (fun i row ->
                row
                |> Seq.iteri (fun k value ->
                    ws.Cells.[iR + i,iC + k].Value <- value))

        //write headers and data
        match headers with
        | Some h ->
            h |> Seq.iteri (fun k value ->
                ws.Cells.[startRow,startCol + k].Value <- value) //write header
            writeData (startRow + 1) startCol       //skip 1 row due to headers and write table body
        | None -> writeData startRow startCol       //write body without skipping 1 row

        let hasHeaders = if Option.isSome headers then true else false

        let tableRange =
            ws.Cells.[
            startRow,   //first row
            startCol,   //first col
            data |> Seq.length |> (+) (if hasHeaders then startRow else startRow - 1), //last row
            data |> Seq.head |> Seq.length |> (+) startCol |> (+) -1] //last col: assumes no sparse data on 1º row
        
        let tb = ws.Tables.Add(tableRange,tableName)
        tb.ShowHeader <- hasHeaders
        
        p.Save())
```

Examples of usage:

```
createTable @"C:\Users\flavi\OneDrive\Documents\testeEPPlusH.xlsx" "SomeTable" "SomeTable" [[1;2;3];[4;5;6];[7;8;9]] (Some ["A";"B";"C"]) (1,1)
```

[image]

```
createTable @"C:\Users\flavi\OneDrive\Documents\testeEPPlusNH.xlsx" "SomeTable" "SomeTable" [[1;2;3];[4;5;6];[7;8;9]] None (1,1)
```

[image]